# Data transformation from int into series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I created a loop to simulate the training for neural network and I find it odd that the weights that was first assigned as an Int turned into a Series

Sample Data (Note: created multiple samples of the same rows to make it up to 100 observations):

```
#         x1    x2  y
data = [ [3.5, 1.5, 1],
         [2.0, 1.0, 0],
         [4.0, 1.5, 1],
         [3.0, 1.0, 0],
         [3.5, 0.5, 1],
         [2.0, 0.5, 0],
         [5.5, 1.0, 1],
         [1.0, 1.0, 0] ]

#[4.5, 1.0, 1]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Length", "Width", "Class"])
data
```

Assigning Variables:

```
w1 = np.random.randn()
w2 = np.random.randn()
b = np.random.randn()

print(w1)
print(w2)
print(b)
```

Training Loop:

```
learning_rate = 0.2
#costs = []

for x in range(50000):
    z = train_data["Length"] * w1 + train_data["Width"] + b
    preds = sigmoid(z)

    target = train_data["Class"]

    cost = np.square(preds - target)


    derivcost_pred = 2 * (preds - target)
    derivpred_sigp = sigmoid_p(z)
    dcost_dz = derivcost_pred * derivpred_sigp

    dz_dw1 = train_data["Length"]
    dz_dw2 = train_data["Width"]
    dz_db = 1

    dcost_dw1 = dcost_dz * dz_dw1
    dcost_dw2 = dcost_dz * dz_dw2
    dcost_db = dcost_dz * dz_db

    w1 = w1 - learning_rate * dcost_dw1
    w2 = w2 - learning_rate * dcost_dw2
    b = b - learning_rate * dcost_db
```

My question here is how to get the last w1, w2, b value that was trained?
Also, if I'll use the series, how can I access the last value instead?

Lastly, let me know If did something wrong with the loop

Comment: Hi there, please post some sample data for . it is more likely you willl get a response if you include some sample data with your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also could explain the second question in more detail: *Also, if I'll use the series, how can I access the last value instead?*? eg. what `series` are you referring to here?

Comment: @edesz - Thanks for the feedback, I updated the post now to provide sample data

Comment: I kinda get it now, it kinda outputs the weights that was used per row..and since I mentioned I created 100 of clones..it would appear that each row will have its own weight..which is not what I expect as I want to have w1,w2, b value to use as a parameter for a single perceptron

Comment: OK, I put an answer to your first question (assuming you want to retrieve the `w1`, `w2`, `b` values corresponding to highest `x` value (`x=5000-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, since you want the  last `w1`, `w2`, `b` value that was trained, I will assume that this corresponds to `x=50000-1`. If this is correct, just add one line to the end of the loop

```
for x in range(50000):
.
.
.
    if x==50000-1: costs.append([w1, w2, b])

# Print results
w1_trained, w2_trained, b_trained = costs[0][0], costs[0][1], costs[0][2]
print(w1_trained, w2_trained, b_trained)
```